# Rails 3.1 Assets in ActionMailer with image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, asset-pipeline

Assets are working fine for my web views, but for some reason my Mailer doesn't use the asset pipeline. I am trying to use an image_tag in my mailer view:

```
=link_to image_tag("logo.png")
```

However, that renders as

```
<img alt="logo" src="http://mydomain.com/assets/logo.png">
```

instead of

```
<img alt="logo" src="http://mydomain.com/assets/logo-xxxxxxxxx...png">
```

Am I missing something here?

My settings are:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => config.domain }
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://" + config.domain
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I know it's almost 3 years later, but I'm running into the same issue :)

Comment: Hey look at that! Ran into it again! Seriously am I taking crazy pills? This does Just Work™ for everyone else, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in your mail template the following instead of the link_to ( the link_to makes no sense because you link here your image to nothing, and I don't see the a href as output in your html) :

```
= asset_path("logo.png")
```

also put in your specific environment file :

```
config.action_mailer.default :content_type => "text/html"
```

Like this you are sure that you always use HTML as default content type. If u are using images in the mails it is better to put it as html.